# conditional aggregate query in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

i am using golang and mongodb.
my `attendance` collection looks like this -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5708156b51230e8edcb01fd1"),
    "college_id" : "tisl",
    "stream" : "CS",
    "semester" : "sem3",
    "section" : "A",
    "subject" : "PH301",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-08T20:32:42.547Z"),
    "teacher" : "Chandra Kanta Bhattacharya",
    "atndnc" : [ 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112115",
            "name" : "Md Hossain Ahamed",
            "attend" : true
        }, 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112116",
            "name" : "Md Sajid Tagala",
            "attend" : true
        }, 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112117",
            "name" : "Nabarun  Roy",
            "attend" : false
        }, 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112118",
            "name" : "Nikunj  Mundra",
            "attend" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get report for each student in percentage as an array of object like:

```
[{"rollno" : "13000112115",
            "name" : "Md Hossain Ahamed",
            "prcntg" : 80},
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112116",
            "name" : "Md Sajid Tagala",
            "prcntg" : 60
        }, 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112117",
            "name" : "Nabarun  Roy",
            "prcntg" : 90
        }, 
        {
            "rollno" : "13000112118",
            "name" : "Nikunj  Mundra",
            "prcntg" : 65
        }]
```

and my conditions will be the following

```
college_id,stream,semester,section,subject,startingdate and enddate
```

Comment: What have you tried and what goes wrong? So far it seems like you are looking for someone to write MongoDB query and go code from scratch without any effort to solve problem by yourself. Sorry but SO is not free service to do the job for you.

Comment: Go write some code and come back to update your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a "write code for me" question.

Comment: This is very unclear as to what you are asking since there is no description of what the "percentage" actually is in terms of calculation. We could "presume" that you mean the number of `true` values as compared to the "total hits" matching the query conditions, but that would be "our guess" rather than what you "clearly" asked. It would be better to show a code "attempt" even if incorrect, so this at least gives some indication of the logic you are trying to achieve.

Comment: db.getCollection('attendance').aggregate([
        {$match: {$and :
            [
                {"stream" : "CS"},
                {"semester" : "sem3"},
                {"section" : "A"}
            ]

        }},
        {$unwind:  '$atndnc'},
        { $group: { _id:{rollno: "$atndnc.rollno",name:"$atndnc.name"},count: { $sum: 1 }}},
        {  $project:
        {  _id: '$_id.rollno',
            'name':'$_id.name',
            'count' : '$count'
        }}
    ])

Comment: this is my query in mongo but i am having problem to write it in golang because it gives the error "missing type in composite literal"

Comment: bson.M{"$group":bson.M{"_id":{"rollno":bson.M{"$atndnc.rollno"}}}}

in this line i am getting that error

Comment: My mongo query is right it gives the wanted result.but in go it give error

Answer (score 1):

> bson.M{"$group":bson.M{"_id":{"rollno":bson.M{"$atndnc.rollno"}}}} in this line i am getting that error

This is due to the incorrect [bson.M](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M) usage. You don't need to create a bson map if its a string (single value). So you could update that to:

```js
bson.M{"$group":
    bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"rollno":"$atndnc.rollno"}}
}
```

The equivalent of your aggregation pipeline in Go is below :

```js
pipeline := []bson.M{ 
        bson.M{"$match": 
            bson.M{"stream": "CS", "semester":"sem3", "section":"A"}},
        bson.M{"$unwind": "$atndnc"},
        bson.M{"$group": 
            bson.M{ "_id": bson.M{"rollno":"$atndnc.rollno", "name":"$atndnc.name"},     
                    "count":bson.M{"$sum":1},
                  },
        }, 
        bson.M{"$project": 
            bson.M{"_id":"$_id.rollno", "name":"$_id.name", "count":"$count"}},
        }
```

I would recommend to checkout [MongoDB mgo driver page](https://labix.org/mgo) for examples and references.

Comment: I believe the error was actually caused by the lack of `bson.M` after `"_id":`. You're right though, they would have encountered an additional error with that string.

Comment: @user161778 tweaked based on your comment.